# How can I move the \Users directory on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to install Windows 7 on a PC - but wish to have the `\Users` directory on some partition/disc other than `C:\`, what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: In retrospect the easiest way was to log in via Audit mode and then use mklink to create a junction from C:\Users -> D:\Users

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on
[How to move the Users Directory in Windows 7](http://lifehacker.com/#!5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7)

Comment: This seems to leave the various winxp compatibility shortcuts pointing at the wrong directory (the old directory at C:\Users rather than the new one).